Nosql databases with temporal collections
Is there a nosql database that supports temporal collections?
Based on relational sql systems, they support temporal tables (it's a secondary table that automatically stores updated or deleted rows from the reference table, thus including periodstart and periodend columns).
Many people perfer change streams. But, working with big data, they are not recomended. Loads of reasons include: too much events (deletemany operation won't emit one event with an object array, instead it emits one by one. Another reason is ttl index (sometimes, an error can occur)...
Another way is to write a background service using backend frameworks (extract documents from last month to a history collection). But, since it's about big data, this could make server errors such as Exception out of memory).
Some people perfer $out operator, but that's not good based on performance, when constantly inserting "sensor" data to the collection. In other words, a system gets 1k insert requests per second.
Is there a way to automatically insert deleted documents to a history collection using a nosql database, without backend support?
Is there a way to automatically insert deleted documents to a history collection using a nosql database, without backend support?
